# avoid partial matches in grep

Tags: r

I want to grep column names and keep exact matches. I'm having trouble avoiding partial matches. Here is a simple example from a more complex use case.

```
keep <- c("A", "AA", "B")  # I get this dynamically in my actual use case
mydata <- data.frame(A=c(1, 1, 1),
                     AA=c(1, 1, 1),
                     B=c(1, 1, 1), 
                     BB=c(1, 1, 1),
                     C=c(1, 1, 1))

pattern <- paste(keep, collapse = "|")
mydata.subset <- mydata[grep(pattern, colnames(mydata), value=TRUE)]
names(mydata.subset)
# [1] "A"  "AA" "B"  "BB"
```

`B` is in `keep`, but not `BB`. How can I exclude partial matches like `BB` without resorting to approaches that specify `BB` explicitly? I'm hesitant to ask for only `grep()` examples, but I think I need to because my actual case is more complex and based on a `grep()` solution.

Also tried

```
mydata.subset <- mydata[grep(pattern, colnames(mydata), fixed=TRUE)]
names(mydata.subset)
# character(0)
```

Comment: You know you can do `mydata[keep]`?

Comment: @flodel: +1 the only difference is that it doesn't keep the original columns order (maybe `keep` vector can be randomly ordered...)

Comment: two helpful answers. learned something new in both. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your pattern in this way :

```
pattern <- paste0('^(',paste(keep, collapse = "|"),')$') # "^(A|AA|B)$"
```

Where `^` means *"start of the string"*, and `$` *"end of the string"*.

Anyway, you can sub-set your data.frame more easily using `%in%` operator :

```
mydata.subset <- mydata[colnames(mydata) %in% keep]
```

Or even simpler (if you are not interested in keeping the original columns order):

```
mydata.subset <- mydata[keep]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
 indx <- grep(paste(paste0("\\b", keep, "\\b"),collapse="|"), colnames(mydata), value=TRUE)
  indx 
  #[1] "A"  "AA" "B" 
 mydata[indx]
 # A AA B
#1 1  1 1
#2 1  1 1
#3 1  1 1
```